Creating a decorator with dynamic parameter
I have some simple decorator that gets an argument:
def deco(name):
    def outer(f):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            print(name)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return inner

    return outer

and a class:
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @deco(self.name) # This is my goal
    def foo(self):
        pass

I want to be able to create few instances of A and each of it will have it's own version of foo (decorated with deco(name)).
This obviously doesn't work as functions are class scope, not instance scope.
I thought about dynamic approach, like:
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        A.foo = deco(name)(A._foo)

    def _foo(self):
        pass

However it has a problem when we create more instances.
Finally I went for that:
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.foo = deco(name)(partial(A._foo, self))

    def _foo(self):
        pass

Which seems to work, however I have a feeling it's too hacky. Do I miss something? My real decorator calculates execution time and store it in database and it's used in many other places like that, so inlining it is not an option.

A cleaner way to implement this is to pass the name of the instance attribute to the decorator and extract self from the first argument passed to inner():
def deco(attr):
    def outer(f):
        def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print(getattr(self, attr))
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

        return inner

    return outer


class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @deco("name")
    def foo(self):
        pass


I really like it for its simplicity, thanks!

Without modifying your existing decorator deco, you can create a decorator factory that returns a decorator that dynamically configures your decorator with self-derived values when called:
def with_self(func):
    def decorator(method):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return func(self)(method)(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@with_self
def deco_name(self):
    return deco(self.name)

class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @deco_name
    def foo(self):
        pass

A('bar').foo()

This outputs:
bar

Demo here
